# Neo4j 3.3.0 community edition Open NLP

Tags: neo4j, opennlp, graphaware

Installed Neo4j CE 3.3.0 on windows RAM 8GB. I referred to https://medium.com/@david.allen_3172/using-nlp-in-neo4j-ac40bc92196f for installation of the open NLP and APOC packages.

Plugins were copied to the `plugins` folder (graphaware-nlp-3.3.0.51.1, graphaware-server-enterprise-all-3.3.0.51 and nlp-opennlp-3.3.0.51.1).

The configuration setting were added to `neo4j.conf` file as given in  https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-nlp

When I restart the Neo4j server, it takes a lot of time and then gives me the following error mesasge:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space Exception in
thread "GraphAware Starter" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while
initializing model of class: class
 opennlp.tools.namefind.TokenNameFinderModel    
    at
 com.graphaware.nlp.processor.opennlp.OpenNLPPipeline.loadModel(OpenNLPPipeline.java:504)
    at
 com.graphaware.nlp.processor.opennlp.OpenNLPPipeline.lambda$loadNamedEntitiesFinders$2(OpenNLPPipeline.java:162)
    at java.util.HashMap$EntrySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown
```

Without the plugins of NLP, Neo4j starts fine. Any help appreciated here on the minimum requirements of RAM/hardware.

Comment: How much data do you have in your database? Also, are the configurations for heap memory in the `neo4j.conf` file on default?

Comment: Went with the default setting same error came up . Also tried with with this setting dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=2048M
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=2048M

Answer (score 0):

The language models require memory to be loaded. So I would suggest to use at least 4GB or more. Furthermore you should use Enterprise version not CE.

Comment: Thanks Allessandro do i have to twek these settings for 4G ? dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=2048M dbms.memory.heap.max_size=2048M

Comment: No, you need to set both to 4096

Comment: Yes i changed to 4096 still no luck how do we check if it has taken this setting

Comment: Try with this:
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=4096m
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=4096m

and check about the java processes for Xmx parameter

Comment: nope it didn't i believe it is not taking the memory settings , i tried using jps and jstat commands to check the memory dont think it is taking the 4096m setting

Comment: No i haven't solved the issue , we have not tried post that as we were busy with other items